# What are the differences of various ways to write dependencies in Gradle?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have seen the following different ways of writing the dependencies in Gradle:

```
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0")
```

and

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
```

and

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
```

Are they all different ways to accomplish the same thing or are there differences among them?

Comment: are you search for another ways or just you need to know the difference

Comment: check this docs https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies

Comment: @ALTegani the latter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`build.gradle` files are just [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) scripts. So its syntax applies here

In Groovy, you can ignore the parenthesis when invoking a function so

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
```

is actually equivalent to

```
implementation('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0')
```

In Groovy you also have [`GString`s](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GString.html) which are represented by `"`. They contains embedded `String`s. In that particular case you're not interpolating any value so both

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
```

and

```
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0"
```

are equivalent. Beware that if you wanted to interpolate some value you'd do

```
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttpVersion" // this line works
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttpVersion' // this line doesn't work
```

`compile` method for defining dependencies is deprecated in favor of `implementation` and `api`. You can find more info [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation). You can consider that if you're exposing somehow the classes of your dependencies you'll use `api` but if you're using the dependencies internally `implementation` is fine

Comment: Great explanation. It's better to understand these underlying concepts than just blindly copy-and-paste.

Answer (score 0):

the `compile` configuration is deprecated and is replaced by `implementation` or `api`.